# macOS Catalina installer customization

Tags: install, software-update

Is it possible to modify the files of the macOS Catalina installer to not require the admin password on install? For example changing a plist or editing an executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can edit it but It won’t pass validation.

- Apple signs the installer so you would have an invalid package after you modified it.

Most people script their modifications to run post install. Same with
   scripting things do run without prompting.